# Need to remove some elements in Json output using XSLT

Tags: json, xml, xslt

I want to remove some element and made a interchange some element in the output of Json from the xml input using XSLT

My Input valid xml file is :

```
         <items>
            <item>
               <statement/>
               <response/>
               <media>
                  <type>img</type>
                  <link>SLP.jpg</link>
               </media>
            </item>
            <item>
               <statement>walking time bomb.</statement>
               <response>
                  <p>Developing additional problems with your health.</p>
               </response>
               <media>
                  <type>html</type>
                  <link>Brightcove.com%2FZ678766-1.avi</link>
               </media>
            </item>
</items>
```

XSL which i used as:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:json="http://json.org/" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

    <xsl:template match="items">
            items: [
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            ]
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="item">
            {
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            },
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="statement">
            "statement": "<xsl:apply-templates/>"
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="response">
            "response": "<xsl:apply-templates/>"
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="media">
            media: {
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            }
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="type">
            "type": "<xsl:apply-templates/>"
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="link">
            <xsl:text>"link": "files/</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(., '/')[last()]"/>"
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="p">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get the output json as:

```
items: [

    {

    "statement": ""

    "response": ""

    media: {

    "type": "img"
    "link": "files/SLP.jpg"

    }

    },

    {

    "statement": "walking time bomb."

    "response": "Developing additional problems with your health."

    media: {

    "type": "html"
"link": "files/Brightcove.com%2FZ678766-1.avi"

    }

    },
```

But i need the output as like below:

```
media: {

        "type": "img"
        "link": "files/SLP.jpg"

        }

        items: [

        {

        "statement": "walking time bomb."

        "response": "Developing additional problems with your health."

        media: {

        "type": "html"
    "link": "files/Brightcove.com%2FZ678766-1.avi"

        }

        },
```

I need the first media file (jpg format) comes separately in the output as like above. Please help me out on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Based on your xslt and your desired output the second item element in your xml should be within an items element within the first item.

Comment: And if you want to exclude empty nodes you will need to change your selectors.

Comment: yes @MatthewWhited. i need that first media element itself comes seperately before the listitem, Because the input xml file is not getting valid if i put the media element outside the listitem element. So only used inside the listitem element. But i need the expected output as like above

Comment: You could move the media type and link to attributes on the root (or items element).  You don't even really need the outer items element defined within your xml.  And as a note your json is not valid as you are missing the commas between properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the first media file to come separately, then you can select it separately by changing the current template matching `items`

```
<xsl:template match="items">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item[1]/media" />
    items: [
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item[position() &gt; 1]"/>
    ]
</xsl:template>
```

All other templates can remain the same.